# When i try to iterate over a pandas_on_spark dataframe, i get error toLocalIterator() is not supported when using file-based collect

Tags: pandas, azure, pyspark, databricks

Running on a Databricks notebook on Azure with pyspark 3.2 running in the cluster. I have code that runs basically like this:

```
a = spark.sql("select ___")
df = a.to_pandas_on_spark()
for x,y in df.iterrows():
    <stuff>
```

However, whenever I run this code, i keep getting an error pointing specifically to the iterrows() line:

**Exception: toLocalIterator() is not supported when using file-based collect**

I'm just trying to iterate through the rows, anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: pandas_on_spark is distributed across worker nodes, so you cannot use a for loop.  Use to_pandas() instead so that all data is collected into a single node first.